# MS Office for Mac questions: ask here, or at superuser?

Tags: discussion, support

Questions about Microsoft Office for Mac (including Excel, Word, Outlook etc) are on-topic both here (tag `ms-office`) and at http://superuser.com - but where's the best place to ask them?

In my experience, there aren't so many people interested in MS software here (`ms-office` tag appears to have 10 followers at the moment), but, superuser has very few Mac users. I'd say I've generally had more luck here in the past, but it's close.

Generally, on both sites, these questions get very few views at first, but then a steady flow of search engine traffic - I think on both sites, I've asked an Office for Mac question, got `tumbleweed` for it, then later on got `popular question` and `notable question` badges for the same question.

In the past, where I've had questions that slip between the cracks, I've asked at one site, then, if it goes full-on tumbleweed, I've asked for it to be migrated to the other.

Is this the best approach? Where would you recommend asking first? Should anything be considered e.g. any time window beyond which questions can't be migrated?

Recent example question: [Stop Excel for Mac (2011) continuing formatting from last cell entered?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119185/stop-excel-for-mac-2011-continuing-formatting-from-last-cell-entered)

---

I asked a similar question to this on meta superuser a while ago: [Where/how can I get answers to questions on Office for Mac?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5669/where-how-can-i-get-answers-to-questions-on-office-for-mac)

Answer (score 4):

In general, either site could host such a question, but we **ask you choose one or the other** and then ask your best phrasing of that one question. If after a week or two, you don't see any action / comment or flag and the moderators of each site can assist in migrating it if needed.

In the end, you'll probably get more users of Office here now that our traffic is grown to a point where SU doesn't dwarf us in eyeballs. (SU is 500k visits daily, we are currently 150k visits daily)

Now, if the topic is clearly about Windows OS interacting with the Mac version, you might ask at Super User first. Alternatively, if you are interested in how Mac specific items relate to the package or working within Mac and iOS ecosystems, then the iOS part makes it off-topic on Super User.

It's more about *who* you want answering the question as opposed to which site has more eyeballs since both sites have active chat rooms where people can assist with editing or promoting a question that isn't getting enough eyeballs.